# show/hide accordion content when icon icon inside <a> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple accordion that is built jquery. It seems to work fine but there is a few issues..

What i mainly need to do is is when someone clicks on the heading text on the accordion, it should redirect to that link when i click on the +/- icon it should toggle the content. I did try to trigger the click to the icon, in that case it completely redirects without showing the content.

Also by default how do i show all the content, rather than clicking?

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Vestibulum 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test2.com">
      Phasellus 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Aliquam cursus vitae nulla non rhoncus. Nunc condimentum erat nec dictum tempus. Suspendisse aliquam erat hendrerit vehicula vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Praesent 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Pellentesque aliquam ligula libero, vitae imperdiet diam porta vitae. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Curabitur 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Donec tincidunt consectetur orci at dignissim. Proin auctor aliquam justo, vitae luctus odio pretium scelerisque. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".set > a").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideUp(200);
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
    } else {
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
      $(this)
        .find("i")
        .removeClass("fa-plus")
        .addClass("fa-minus");
      $(".set > a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".content").slideUp(200);
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideDown(200);
    }
  });
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/oaj471bm/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after

```
$(".set > a").on("click", function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        window.location.assign( $(this).attr("href") );
        return;   // other code doesn't get executed if the redirect was unsuccessful 
    }

     // other code
 });
```

As you see above you need to get the event `e` from the `onclick` listener which then helps us figure out the target element that was clicked.

With `$(e.target).is('a')` we can check if the clicked element is an anchor tag in which case we want a redirect. If the clicked element is the child element `i` the above `if` condition won't be satisfied.

Check below:

**Note:** The script works, but won't change browser location here since you are using `http://` instead of `https://` which is blocked as insecure (check console after clicking).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".set > a").on("click", function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
      window.location.assign( $(this).attr("href") );
      return;
    }
  
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideUp(200);
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
    } else {
      $(".set > a i")
        .removeClass("fa-minus")
        .addClass("fa-plus");
      $(this)
        .find("i")
        .removeClass("fa-plus")
        .addClass("fa-minus");
      $(".set > a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(".content").slideUp(200);
      $(this)
        .siblings(".content")
        .slideDown(200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #567;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.accordion-container{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.accordion-container > h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.set{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.set > a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.set > a i{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.set > a.active{
  background-color:#3399cc;
  color: #fff;
}
.content{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display:none;
}
.content p{
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6cea534c30.js"></script>

<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Vestibulum 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test2.com">
      Phasellus 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Aliquam cursus vitae nulla non rhoncus. Nunc condimentum erat nec dictum tempus. Suspendisse aliquam erat hendrerit vehicula vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Praesent 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Pellentesque aliquam ligula libero, vitae imperdiet diam porta vitae. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a href="http://test.com">
      Curabitur 
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <p> Donec tincidunt consectetur orci at dignissim. Proin auctor aliquam justo, vitae luctus odio pretium scelerisque. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But there is a problem.. When i use this code and click on the title it expands but when i click on the +/- it redirects. I need it to the other way around. When i click on the title it should redirect and the +/- should expand

Comment: @LiveEn Let me know if this edit solves your problem

Comment: perfect.. Thank you for the detailed explanation